# Running two Functions after one another Rake Rails4 failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, task

On a rainy Saturday afternoon, I am encountering the following issue. When I am running in the rails console two actions after another they are failing (the second one is).

What I am doing is

> rails console 
>   require 'extractor/myfile'
>   MyClass.Task1
>   (Evernthing is fine at this stage)
>   MyClass.Task2
>   (Just get [] as awesome answer)

The magic is when I do:

> Exit
>   rails console 
>   require 'extractor/myfile'
>   MyClass.Task2

It is not going to fail (runs normally). The logs don't seem to provide much help, so was wondering what makes things fail . Bundeling them in a rake task does not help much either. Would love to hear from the community.

These are the two functions in the class:

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'net/ftp'
# these are for the AWS upload
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

# This is a simple logging class
require 'logger' 
# Location for the Logger

class FileUpload

def self.download_from_s3

      FileUtils::mkdir_p("lib/extractor/temp/dataupload") unless Dir.pwd.include? "lib/extractor/temp/dataupload"  
      Dir.chdir("lib/extractor/temp/dataupload" ) unless  Dir.pwd.include? "/lib/extractor/temp/dataupload" 

      # Get an instance of the S3 interface.
      s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => 'access',
                                :secret_access_key => 'secret')
      my_bucket = s3.buckets['bucketname']
      # Upload a file.
      #key = File.basename(filename)s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].read(:file => filename)
      File.open(Time.now.to_i.to_s + '_large.CSV', 'wb') do |file| 
      my_bucket.objects.each do |obj|

        file.write(my_bucket.objects[obj.key].read)
      end
    end


end
  # count number of files


def self.upload
    Dir['lib/extractor/temp/dataupload/*'].each do |item|
    puts item
    if item == '.' or item == '..'
       # do not do anything with these
       puts "starting"
    else 
       Net::FTP.open('ftp.example.com', 'userftp', 'password') do |ftp|
       ftp.passive = true 
       ftp.putbinaryfile(item)

       File.delete(item)
      end
    end
  end
end



end
```

Comment: You mean, this is wrong that, in case of calling Task1 berfore Task2, Task2 returns empty array? And if you call Task2 first, it gives some other output?
It is hard to say anything without real code and backtrace output (in case of exception)

Comment: Hey, yeah but to me it happens in multiple cases. But indeed it is what I meant. So if I run task II after I the second returns an empty array

Comment: The first thing coming up on the mind is that you functions are somehow dependent on each other. Or they modify some common entities, variables, database record etc.

Comment: Post the code please. The only reason for that I can think of is that the functions are interfearing with each other throuh coupling of some internal params. No way to give you a discreet answer withought looking at the actual code.

Comment: Done! See original question. Thanks @Almaron and the others